# R plumber on Linux Server

Tags: r, linux, api, server, plumber

I've made a .R file with a plumber code. The file works fine on my local pc, it works also fine on my linux server.
My only problem now is, that it's only local.

I need to be able to get the API over the server adress.
The server also runs a cronR process which makes all the math and a shiny-app to display some graphs. All the math is stored into an cvs file and plumber should now get the last index and display this so I can use it from everywhere.

Are there any solutions?

Code:

```
library(plumber)

path = "/srv/shiny-server/Crypto10/data/"

r = plumb(paste(path,"API.R", sep = ""))  

r$run(port=8000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
r$run(host="0.0.0.0",port=8000)
```